# how to import font styling in vue js project

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, fonts

I'm trying to implement certain font on my vue project, but the font seems not working, this is how i import the font locally in my App.vue file

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Open Sans Bold";
  src: local("OpenSans-Bold"), url("./fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf"), format("truetype");
  font-weight: bold;
}'
```

this is how i use it on my Home.vue file

```
 .router-link-active{
      font-family: "Open Sans Bold";
      color: #5F5F5F !important;
      text-decoration: underline;
      text-underline-position: under;
      text-decoration-thickness: 3px;
    }
```

did i make any mistake?

Comment: Do you wants to add the font family style to the entire project?

Comment: You will need to use chrome dev tools to inspect and check it if your font family in `.router-link-active` class is overwriting by others or not. If yes then u will need to write a more specific css selector to your element

Comment: yea i want to add those fonts on my entire project @Jebasuthan

Comment: @someone_that_needHelp Checkout my below answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add font to your vue project with two approaches.

**Apprach 1:**

*Step 1:* Create a seperate folder for font inside assets folder

*Step 2:* Under font folder place your fonts

*Step 3:* Refer the font inside public folder index.html

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

**Apprach 2:**

*Step 1:* Create a seperate folder inside assets folder for css

*Step 2:* Under css folder create new `style.css` and place your font style

```
@font-face { 
  font-family: "Open Sans Bold";
  src: local("OpenSans-Bold"), url("./fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf"), 
  format("truetype");
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

*Step 3:* Refer the the css inside `src/main.js`

```
import './assets/css/style.css'
```

[image: Folder structure]

For more details you can refer the [Github Project Link](https://github.com/Jebasuthan/vue_crud_bootstrap)